# Regex: why doesn‘t this catch multiple double-letter occurrences?

Tags: regex

I‘d like to write a regular expression allowing me to find all lines in a text file containing three or more doubled letters (“oo”, “ss”, “tt”, etc). Here’s a command that I successfully used to find lines with two or more doubled letters:

```
egrep ‘(([A-Za-z])\2.*){2,}’ sherlock.txt
```

One example of a line produced by running this command is the following:

```
I had seen little of Holmes lately. My marriage had drifted us away from each
```

This line actually contains *three* doubled letters (“ee”, “tt”, and “rr”). However, when I used the following command to print lines with three or more doubled letters, there was no output:

```
egrep ‘(([A-Za-z])\2.*){3,}’ sherlock.txt
```

Why isn’t this code working? What am I missing?

Comment: `(([A-Za-z])\2.*){3,}` [matches your string, too](https://regex101.com/r/G8BGYp/1)

Comment: Try this: (([A-Za-z])\2.*?)+ The problem comes from the fact you're using GREEDY matching

Comment: it better to put `.*` first `(.*(\w)\2){3}` but either way should work,  even `(.*(\w)\2){3}.*` if needer whole string

Answer (score -1):

As you didn't give language/tool you are using, here is a perl oneliner that does the job:

**Input file:**

```
cat file.txt 
I had seen little of Holmes lately. My marriage had drifted us away from each
I had seen Holmes lately. My marriage had drifted us away from each
```

**Perl:**

```
perl -anE '@l=$_=~/(\w)\1/g;say if @l>2' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
I had seen little of Holmes lately. My marriage had drifted us away from each
```